# Is my server secure enough now?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, security

Ok, so my server got hacked last week. The hacker attacked an out-of-date 3rd party editor (in php) and implanted a backdoor script in PHP and did serious damages to my sites. I spent a whole weekend cleaning the backdoor scripts and any malicious codes he left on my server. And in order to avoid being hacked again, I did the following to my server:

1. turn off file_upload in PHP. Since the hacked uploaded the backdoor through PHP, I disabled the function in php.ini. So now I can only upload through ftp.
2. disable create_function in php. None of my software uses this function. The hacker used this function the same way as eval() to execute commands in as strings.
3. disable popen,exec,system,passthru,proc_open,shell_exec,show_source,phpinfo in php.ini. These functions are primarily used by the back door script to modify my files and directories.
4. Install suhosin. Find legal functions that are called within eval(), put them in the suhosin.executor.eval.whitelist. Hacker put malicious codes in my program, and obfiscated it with base64_encode, and then execute them within eval(). So I only allow a couple of legal functions being called within eval().
5. Turn on suhosin.executor.disable_emodifier. The hacker put another obfiscated code in my program, and used preg_replace() e modifier to execute whatever php commands he put on his browser. So he could upload or modify any files on the server through his browser. (Since I turned off file_upload, he could not upload any more, but still he could modify and delete files as he wanted).

By disabling the create_function, preg_replace() e modifier and limiting eval(), even there are malicious codes left uncleaned on my server, the hacker could not do anything. These are the 3 most dangerous functions in PHP.

1. Add .htaccess to every folder but the root directory and forbidding PHP from being executed directly from browser:

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all

I put another * after Php because I found a backdoor file that was named as missing.php.DISABLED and this can still be executed if I do not put * after php

1. Set the root directory (the only place that allows to execute .php) as read only. Set all files in that folder read-only. So the hacker could not upload any new back door script to the only directory where the php can be executed. Neither could he modify the files in that directory.
2. For the wordpress login, I added

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all

allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

to the .htaccess in the root directory, where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is my ip.

1. Set all .htaccess read only.

Well, this is what I can do to strenthen the security of my server. Did I miss anything?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: So you were protecting from yourself?

Comment: Nobody but you knows what other exploitable holes you have. Most problems are in code you wrote, not necessarily the server configuration.

Comment: Where is the part about _"from now on I will always keep my 3rd party code up to date"_? It's still not a guarantee but if there is any lesson to learn, it's this.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Even if there are still exploitable holes left, can the hacker still do anything with all these limitations?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you reimaged the machine from known-clean install media, you can't know there isn't a lingering rootkit.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Is there any way or software I can find lingering rootkit? How can I prevent these rootkits being executed? I appreciate your advice.

Comment: Not that you should rely on.  The whole point of a rootkit is to evade that sort of detection, so you're instantly into an arms race.